# Make method of Twig-safe function also Twig-safe

Tags: php, twig

I have defined a Twig function like this:

```
new Twig_SimpleFunction('link', 'html_link', ['is_safe' => ['html']]);
```

so every `{{ link(...) }}` isn't auto-escaped by Twig. That works.

But `html_link()` returns a `Link` object that can be tweaked in the template, to add a URL `#fragment` or link `[attribute]`:

```
{{ link('url', 'label').withFragment('foo') }}
{{ link('url', 'label').withClass('special') }}
```

But Twig detects that it's not a pure `link()` anymore, so it's not html-safe anymore, and I have to add `|raw` to make it work:

```
{{ link('url', 'label').withFragment('foo')|raw }}
{{ link('url', 'label').withClass('special')|raw }}
```

Which works. But. Not very pretty.

Can I tell Twig that `link().withFragment()` and `link().withClass()` are still html-safe?

Custom filters have an option `preserves_safety` that kinda works kinda like that:

```
{{ someFunction(someVar)|someFilter }}
```

If `someFunfction` is html-safe, and `someFilter` was defined with `preserves_safety`, the output is still safe. I don't want to make filters for ever `Link` method, so that's not quite good enough.

---

I can't use `Twig_Markup`, because:

- It has to remain an object as long as possible (`withFragment`, `withClass` etc return `$this`), so you can do multiple things to it, e.g. add a class AND a fragment.
- It must be usable outside of Twig. E-mails and flash messages can include links. Only Twig knows (and should know) what a `Twig_Markup` is. Since it's not an interface, I can't add it to the `Link` class.

Comment: Make the methods return the following `return new \Twig_Markup($value, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @DarkBee That sounds like an answer. I'd like to reply to it.

Comment: Issue one you could solve with the magic function `__toString()` though, something like [this](https://ideone.com/y2GgSx).

The second isssue will be harder, I'm not sure there is a solution for this constraint

Comment: Yes, my Link class has a `__toString`. That's why it already works. Everything works. Only Twig considers the output unsafe.

Comment: What about creating your own `Twig_Markup` class when it not exists?

Comment: My own class? I have my own class: `Link`. It's the chainable, tostringable class with the useful methods. I could make it extend `Twig_Markup`, but that's too weird and wrong.

Comment: Yeah sthing like `if(!class_exists('Twig_Markup')) { class Twig_Markup { ... } }` it's weird but prolly the only way to do in in `PHP` and remove the `twig` constraint

Comment: @Rudie if your `Link::__toString()` method always returns safe content, then what is wrong with making the class extend `Twig_Markup`?

Comment: It already extends something (`HtmlString`, similar, but from another lib), but that's not even the real issue. You shouldn't extend something because it 'works'. You should extend something because it 'fits'. I'm using it outside Twig too, so it isn't (doesn't fit) a `Twig_Markup`.

Comment: When called by autoe-escaping, Twig's core escape filter checks to see if an object is an instance of Twig_Markup to consider its content safe for raw output. Seems the content of an object of your `Link` class is always safe for raw output, and considering the fact that you're writing an extension _for Twig_, it makes sense to extend `Twig_Markup` if possible and it actually fits. Regarding the conflict with extending `HtmlString`, I think that's Twig's fault for using `instanceof` against a concrete class name instead of an interface.

Comment: @Nima I'm not writing an extension for Twig.... `Link` is used outside of Twig too, so I **don't** want it coupled. I agree 100% about the `instanceof class` instead of interface: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2792